# Clarification on linked-list node

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to understand what a linked-list node is. What is passed to the constructors? In particular, what is node* head? It is a pointer to the structure itself. How does a linked-list fit in with this structure?

```
struct node {
    node* next;
    int data;
    explicit node(int data) : node(nullptr, data) {}
    node(node* head, int data) : next(head), data(data) {}
}
```

EDIT::

I should be more clear with my question. I know that I can manually define each node and initialize them and keep doing that to create a list. But how do I implement a list from the node without specifying what I want each time? I guess what I am getting at is I am unsure how to build a list from the node just given this definition for a node.

Comment: A quick google will give you many tutorials/descriptions for linked lists:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson15.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's focus on a single node first:

```
--------
| data |
--------
| next |
--------
```

Obviously, `data` member holds the data for the current node. So, node is just pair of `data` holder, and pointer to the next element in the list (`next`). Now, the name "linked" list tells you that this kind of data structure is a connected by some links. So you may have multiple nodes, chained together, like this:

```
--------     --------       --------
| 5    |     | 3    |     | 6       |
--------     --------      --------
| next | --->| next | --->| nullptr |
--------     --------      --------
```

It is pretty easy to find what node is our last node in the list - it is that one in which the value of the `next` pointer is `nullpointer`, indicating that there are no more nodes in the list.

But, how we will find the first element of the list? We will do that by keeping `head` pointer - pointer to the first element of the list somewhere in the memory:

```
--------     --------       --------
| 5    |     | 3    |     | 6       |
--------     --------      --------
| next | --->| next | --->| nullptr |
--------     --------      --------

  ^
  |
 head
```

By storing `head` pointer, we can easily traverse the list like this:

```
node *tmp = head; // tmp is our "iterator" through the list
while(tmp != nullptr) 
{
   // Print the data
   cout << tmp->data;

   // Move iterator to the next element
   // Note that when we print the last element,
   // tmp will become nullptr, and the loop will break!
   tmp = tmp->next;
}
```

> I should be more clear with my question. I know that I can manually define each node and initialize them and keep doing that to create a list. But how do I implement a list from the node without specifying what I want each time? I guess what I am getting at is I am unsure how to build a list from the node just given this definition for a node.

There is one clever trick to do that - you can keep the `last` pointer somewhere, and you can create a helper function, for example:

```
void insert(int data)
{
    node* n = new node(data);

    // If the list is empty:
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
       // This element becomes the first!
       head = n;
    }
    else
    {
       // Append this element to the end of the
       // list
       last->next = n;
    }

    // Update last, as this is the last
    // element in the list
    last = n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`node* head` is the first instantiation of `node` to which you've obviously kept a reference/handle.  The subsequent instantiations form the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is a series of things joined together one to the next. Each thing in the list is (or is held by) a "node", so a linked-list node is an entry in a linked list. In the example you give the node is a structure with room for a value ("data") plus room for a pointer to the next list node.

The first constructor in your example initialises a node but does not link it into a list.
The second one creates a node and makes it the head of a list. Your list is built by pushing new nodes onto its head. The head is the first node in the list, and all the others can be reached by following the "next" pointer, starting from the head.

Answer (score 0):

Linked-list node is literally a node of Linked-list, which have data fields and a pointer to the next node. Like what your code has already showed.

```
struct node {
    node* next;
    int data;
    explicit node(int data) : node(nullptr, data) {}
    node(node* head, int data) : next(head), data(data) {}
}
```

The `node *head` is more clear if it is put in a linkedlist struct, which makes linkedlist operation more convenient to do. For example:

```
struct linkedlist {
   node *head;
   linkedlist();
   node *getHead();
   node *getNext();
   void traverse_list();
   ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wikipedia helps clarifying the issue: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Basic_concepts_and_nomenclature

the nomenclature says: head is the first element, whereas tail refers to the rest.